# What do you call the state of a screen being divided into two with 2 different footages showing at the same time?

Tags: vocabulary

> The movie transitioned into a ____ of a man piloting an aircraft in
>   first person and of the aircraft flying in the air at the speed of
>   sound in third person.

I can't think of a word for this, and I am not sure if you can use "the of x and of y" construction. I think it's idiomatic, but I haven't really seen any example from a reputable source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split screen (or split-screen) in film and video production, is the visible division of the screen, usually in half.

[Split screen (video production)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_screen_(video_production))

Typical usage:

> ...everyone loves a creatively-infused, mind-bending example of a good
>   split screen

[Split screens](https://nofilmschool.com/2018/03/split-screens-watch)

[image]

[Split screen](http://filmstudies.info/terminology/manuscripts/split-screen.html)